# Delete user with only subscriber role

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have a site which have 90k+ user with subscriber roles.I want delete user with only subscriber role using phpmyadmin . So I know how to delete it But some users have multiple roles for example few users have both editor and subscriber role . Now my query is deleting all the user which subscriber roles including users which have multiple roles but I don't want that .So what should I update in my query to delete users which have only subscriber role.
This is my current query

```
DELETE FROM  wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'AND meta_value  LIKE '%subscriber% .
```

Any advice will be helpfull and thanks in advance and can anyone tell is this query also deleting fields in wp_usermeta right?

Comment: I'd avoid a diirect database query if I were you. Do you have access to the server via the terminal? Because you could then use WP CLI https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/delete/ - e.g. `wp user delete $(wp user list --role=subscriber --field=ID)`.
Your query won't delete user meta or posts or anything related to the user in other tables.

Comment: Will this command delete user with only subscriber role ? And will this also delete meta?

Comment: Unfortunately, it would also delete users with multiple roles, I just did a quick test. You'll probably need a custom CLI command. I'll try and find some time to write one

Comment: Aah ok thanks is there any plugin which can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pdewouters/single-role-user-delete/main/plugin.php)

Please run with `--dry-run` first and also do a full database backup!